# How to draw a bar diagram on Android

Tags: android, graph, bar-chart, diagram, android-custom-view

I need to draw a bar diagram like the picture showing below. I am able to draw a ordinary bar diagram with filling a color on text view or some layouts. But this is a bit different. 
How do I draw a bar diagram with slanting bars?

[image].

Comment: I guess you should create your own CustomView

Comment: have a look at this library as starting point: https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView

Comment: No, i never use any 3 party lib. I really dont know how to curve or to slant the bar diagram.

Comment: Maybe this guy https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/overview could show us the direction how to achieve that slanting bars.

Comment: have you found solution? i need to draw diagram like it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845262/advice-about-android-custom-view

Answer (score 1):

Try Android canvas and custom View. You can use View's onDraw method. The method provides the canvas. You should try drawArc, drawLine, etc. If your bar view contains a textView, you must use a custom viewgroup.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any example for this. ?

Comment: No, I havn't but you shoul read website--> http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your onDraw of View.

```
RectF oval = new RectF();
Paint paint  = new Paint();
paint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color1));
paint.setStrokeWidth(widthOfArc);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
canvas.drawPath(path, yourPaint);
oval.set(x1,y1,x2,y2);
//eg:-  startAngle = 10, sweepAngle = 40
canvas.drawArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle, false, paint);
```

Please read about how RectF works.
I will update the answer if I found any related blog/tutorial

Calculating start and end angle is pure Mathematics
refer this
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/

You have to change the color and keep drawing Arc to get the result.